# how to separate password recovery from jwt authentication

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, change-password

In the process of implementing password recovery feature I tried to test the basic behavior before moving forward with the implementation but every time I try submit a HTTP request I get the error message :

> JWT expired at 2023-07-19T13:31:51Z. Current time:
> 2023-07-23T10:31:30Z, a difference of 334779299 milliseconds.  Allowed
> clock skew: 0 milliseconds.

I tried to add the password recovery endpoint as one that does not require any jwt authentication in the **FilterChain** method but still the same error occurs.

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
```

and here's the
the method for processing the email from the HTTP request:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ForgotPasswordController {

    @PostMapping("/password_recovery")
    public String processEmail(@RequestParam("email") String email) {

        String generatedToken = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        System.out.println("Email: " + email);
        System.out.println("Token: " + generatedToken);
        return "Your password recovery token: " + generatedToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to return your new generated token if in case it gets expired within certain time?

Comment: yes i want to return the newly generated token as a response so that the user can use it in the next step to change the password but at this level I'm just trying to test if the endpoint works and the request passes yet it keeps responding based on the jwt token. it's like i'm trying to authenticate

Comment: i hope you are aware that using JWTs as sessions is insecure and that is why there is no such implementation in spring security. Writing a custom filter for that is writing custom security which is bad practice. Dont use JWTs as sessions. Instead of following bad blogs/tutorials, read the spring security documentation and implement security as dictated there.

Answer (score 0):

When the user hits an endpoint with expired JWT,the user gets 401 unauthorized as response from spring server.
You can create two filters for that in `Security Configurer`.
One `tokenValidationFilter` that will stand right before at
`addFilterBefore`

And another filter,in your case it is `jwtAuthFilter`

```
  http.addFilterBefore(tokenValidationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

  http.addFilterAfter(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

when user hits the endpoint with expired token and it is caught by `tokenValidationFilter` filter.

You can extract claims from that expired token and generate new token with new expiration time with same old claims.

You can get tons of libraries to decode your JWT Token.

For example you can extract user object from claims that was present in old token.

you can return that token as payload with 401 status.

for example
in your `tokenValidationFilter` filter

`response.getWriter().write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(Map.of("token", jwtTokenService.createJwtToken(user, false))))`

when user interceptor receives unauthorized request with key "token".
you can set it in header in your frontend side.

If you understand the flow of authentication,You can figure it out.

Comment: the authentication works as intended but the problem is that it keeps checking the jwt token while it is not even necessary since I am implementing a password recovery service that evolves around a completely other token. That said, I am asking on how to separate these two processes : the authentication with jwt token and the password recovery